# Disable scaling/increasing Polyline when zoom out/in the map

Tags: android, google-maps, drawing, polyline

My app draws your route by adding Polylines. The user sets color, width and transparent. The only problem is that I dont want to change the size of polylines but when I zoom out or zoom in map then polyline's size change. 
Anyone know how to disable that "size changing" function?

Comment: I think it's only normal that when you zoom in or out the size of the image will adjust as well. For example buildings that look small will increase in size as you zoom in. And the oppposite happens when you zoom-out. Try to read more on [Google Maps Zoom levels](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Zoomlevels) for additional insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

`yourPolyLine.setWidth(yourIntegerValue)`

For more detail of in google maps you can refer [this](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples) link.

For to not scaling polyline in map when user zoom in/out, you have to set polyline width. To do this you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25773671/4684984) link.

Comment: `mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraMove() {
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = mMap.getCameraPosition();
                if(cameraPosition.zoom > 0) {
                    for (Polyline p : polylineArrayList)
                        p.setWidth(CircleRadius / yourValue); //yourValue depends on what cameraPosition.zoom is
                }`